# Flutter extracting data from a list inside a map from API call

Tags: api, flutter, rest

I have a flutter http get request that returns a response in the below format

```
{
   
    "area": "some area",
    "user_places": [
        {
            "place_id": "105",
            "place_name": "Place 1"
        },
        {
            "place_id": "104",
            "place_name": "place 2"
        }
    ],
    "lang": null,
    "token": "IiwiZGV2aWNlIjoid2ViIiwiZGllIjoiMjAyMS0wNS0xMiAyMjo0NTozOSJ9.2wJlmHNRmQ0_rfNbca2-DNek1dzT9Em8-iQIfGFZJ98",
    "account_type": 1,
    
}
```

Am currently able to get data from a field directly below the map for example `"area"` .
My question is how to get data from a list inside the map in this case `"user_places"`. Say I wanted to display all `"place_id"` and `"place_name"` in a widget somewhere in my app. How would I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a tool like [json to dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) you can paste your json data and get a dart class of the same

```
class MyLocation {
  String area;
  List<UserPlaces> userPlaces;
  String lang;
  String token;
  int accountType;

  MyLocation(
      {this.area, this.userPlaces, this.lang, this.token, this.accountType});
....
```

then `MyLocation.userPlaces` you can access your data